# CLLocation is not submitted to iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

I have a question concerning the WCSession `transferUserInfo` method. When I try to send a `CLLocation` object from the Apple Watch to the owning iPhone, the corresponding receive method is never called. The code on the watch side looks like follows (shortened of course):

```
class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController, WCSessionDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if WCSession.default.activationState == .activated {
            let userInformation = ["MyLocation" : locations.last] as [String : Any]
            WCSession.default.transferUserInfo(userInformation)
        }
        else {
            os_log("Can not send session data", type: .error)
        }
}

}
```

The iPhone counterpart code:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController, WCSessionDelegate {

func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveUserInfo userInfo: [String : Any] = [:]) {        
        let location = userInfo["MyLocation"] as? CLLocation
        if location == nil {
            os_log("Location not found", type: .error)
        }

        os_log("RX DATA : %@", location.description)
}

}
```

When I replace the location object by a string, everything works as expected. The string will be delivered to the iPhone.

Why is the `CLLocation` object not delivered but the string is? How can I configure XCode to show me the error/reason? Currently nothing happens, not even an error is shown.

Thank you

Comment: Please edit your question to make it on-topic as explained in the help page: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)._

Comment: Question rephrased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user info dictionary only accepts property list types.

`CLLocation` isn't one, but `Data` is and `CLLocation` implements `NSCoding` so you can use a keyed archiver/unarchiver to convert it to `Data` and back.

Convert it to data on the watch:

```
if let location = locations.last {
    let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: location)
    // put the data in your user info and send it along
}
```

Then convert it back to a location on the phone:

```
if let data = userInfo["MyLocation"] as? Data,
    let location = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? CLLocation {
    // do whatever with the location
}
```